# R Terra: as.polygons potentially undesireable behavior with categorical raster

Tags: r, gis, terra

I am working with the LANDFIRE BPS https://www.landfire.gov/bps.php dataset and am trying to generate polygons from the different categories for a broader analysis. I am performing it on western North America. This is best illustrated using the zone category. My set up code is

```
pkgs <- c("sf", "tidyverse", "terra", "RColorBrewer")
invisible(lapply(pkgs, library, character.only = T))
bps <- rast("BPS/DIRECTORY")
bps_ext <- ext(bps)
bps_ext[2] <- 0 #builds wna ext quickly
bps_wna <- crop(bps,bps_ext)
activeCat(bps_wna) <- 2 #ZONE category
bps_wna_1km <- aggregate(bps_wna, 33,fun = "modal") #for computation resources, convert to 1 km
plot(bps_wna_1km) #beware, there are not enough colors with this color scheme, so there are repeats, see zone 10
# and 20
```

[image]

This plot clearly shows what we could draw boundaries around. It makes sense 
I then run

```
bps_polygon_zone <- as.polygons(bps_wna_1km,dissolve =T,na.rm = T,trunc = F)
plot(bps_polygon_zone, col = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(12,"Set3"), lwd = 0.01)
```

[image]

This behavior is very strange. It doesn't appear to be properly drawing around the zones. Lets try working in SF because maybe it's just splitting into multiple polygons

```
bps_polygon_zone_sf <- st_as_sf(bps_polygon_zone) %>%
group_by(ZONE) %>%
summarize(geometry = st_union(geometry))
plot(vect(bps_polygon_zone_sf), col = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(12,"Set3"), lwd = 0.01)
```

[image]
This Looks MUCH better. Those little dark spots are just NA which I want to remove anyway.
I want to transition BPS_CODE, ZONE, and BPS_MODEL to polygons to allow for easier computations down the line, however with this type of behavior I feel quite uncomfortable doing it in terra. I feel dissolve should be creating the last polygons because it should dissolve over the same feature (i.e. zone). However, as.polygons() does not appear to be dissolving properly. Robert, since you are the primary maintainer, what is your opinion on this behavior with as.polygon? For reference, my current terra version is a bit old, 1.6-47. I am hesitant to update terra because I have a lot of code using terra heavily and the last thing I want to do for this operation is to update and have it all break. Let me know if there are any issues with the reprex, description, etc.

Comment: From the URL provided it is not clear what file you are using. Can you please point to a specific URL? And you really should update terra first. A workaround is probably to use `dissolve=FALSE` and then `aggregate`

Answer (score 1):

You have a categorical `SpatRaster` where many category IDs point to the same label for the active category.  `as.polygons` does not consider that. Perhaps it should, but here is a work-around (`aggregate` the polygons).

Example data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10)
set.seed(0)
values(r) <- sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
cls <- data.frame(id=1:3, cover=c("forest", "water", "urban"), zone=c("A", "A", "B"))
cls
#  id  cover zone
#1  1 forest    A
#2  2  water    A
#3  3  urban    B

levels(r) <- cls
activeCat(r) <- "zone"
```

Solution

```
p <- as.polygons(r)
pa <- aggregate(p, "zone")
```

Illustration

```
plot(r)
lines(p)
lines(pa, col="red", lwd=3)
```

[image]

Comment: that makes sense. Thank you for clearing it up. I figured it was a categorical raster oddity. It's all figured out now. Thank you for your time!